# How to make setState with nested object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

How do I use setState if am having nested object. I have a json list using that I update this state. but Suppose if I want to update only a Phone Number field in this state then how  do I make it. Below code gives me error

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   myData: {
             ...prevState.myData,
             user: { ...prevState.myData.user, PhoneNumber: value }
            }
}));

interface IData  {
    ID:number,
    usage:string,
    user:IUser
}

interface IUser{
    name:string,
    PhoneNumber:number
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this is to create a clone of the object that you want to update, then update that clone using javascript as you desire, then set the state using that clone object. 
Like this:

```
let clone = {...objectInStateToUpdate};
  // Do operations on clone as desired
this.setState({objectInStateToUpdate: clone});
  // or if you named the cloned same as your object
this.setState({clone});
```

Hope it helps!